# Angular Material - Why does sticky footer works with version 1.3.2, but not with version 1.5.7

Tags: angularjs

See this codepen: https://codepen.io/rscafi/pen/bNXRxY , an example of a sticky footer made with angular 1.3.2:

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.css">
```

If you change the version from 1.3.2 to 1.5.7 like this:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
<!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
<script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Angular Material Library -->
 <script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material-icons/0.7.1/angular-material-icons.min.js"></script>
```

It doesnt work anymore. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

the fix is remove `layout="column"` or `layout-fill` in the root div

`<div ng-app="materialApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" layout-fill>`

What happen is

> It doesnt work anymore

It **still work** but I think in new *angular-material.min.css* the `<footer>` load into the DOM by layout-fill, layout-fill forces the layout element to fill its parent container, mean the `<footer>...</footer>` placed in the bottom of the window (parent) not the page (child `<div>...</div>` )

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options

### update

Furthermore, if you want it sticky you even no need to delete but add more, so you split your page into 3 sections with
 `<md-toolbar>` and `<md-content>`

### update

edit CSS file with

```
md-content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 176px)
}
```

check this out

http://embed.plnkr.co/4TEtW9eQK0iXH4GYhSe9/

Comment: That doesn't work when there is no content(screenshot): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8IlXEex0TtobHZuWVRGUjZNLWM/view

Comment: I just update CSS file for the <md-content> and a Plnkr for your test